# How to fetch all comments of PHP files using C#?

Tags: c#, php, regex, parsing

I've got a requirement for parsing PHP files in C#. Basically I need all the comments in PHP files and I want to translate all that comments into another language using Google Translate.

I am currently doing this by using regular expressions. But it is in vain. If I parse "// or /*..*/ " I am unable to identify whether these two lie within a string.

Let's say `$i= " http://wwww.google.como " ;`. My regular expression considers it as comments `"//wwww.google.com " ;`, whereas it is not a comment. So can anybody help me out?

Is there anything already built which helps me a lot, like php parser, etc?

Comment: Does it have to be codes in C#, or products/solutions in other languages are acceptable?

Comment: i need it in .net. but what you suggest me if i say yes ?

Comment: PHP's lexical structure is pretty complicated; check out string literals, and then of course you can have HTML text in a PHP which in worst case might contain stuff that looks like PHP code.   Unless you want to write a full PHP lexer, you are likely to get this wrong, you'll end up finding "//" inside some strange docstring.   Another answer here suggested using PHP itself (which contains a full tokenizer) to do the work; I think that approach is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trivial php script that accepts a php script filename and tokenizes it for you using [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php)

After that work with that output (which is a token stream and easy to deal with)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a series of state to do so instead of regular expression. For example (this is pseudocode, you can convert it to any language you want):

```
bool isPHP = false
bool isMultiComment = false
bool isSingleComment = false
bool isSingleQuote = false
bool isDoubleQuote = false
string comments[]

for i := 0 -> phpcode.length()
   if !isPHP && (phpcode[i->5] == '<?php') then
      isPHP = true
   elseif isPHP && (phpcode[i->2] == '?>') then 
      isPHP = false
   elseif isPHP && !(isSingleQuote || isDoubleQuote)
                && !(isSingleComment || isMultiComment) 
                && (phpcode[i->2] == '/*') then
      isMultiComment = true
      comments.add("");
   elseif isPHP && !(isSingleQuote || isDoubleQuote)
                && !(isSingleComment || isMultiComment) 
                && (phpcode[i->2] == '//') then
      isSingleComment = true
      comments.add("");
   elseif isPHP && isMultiComment
                && (phpcode[i->2] == '*/') then
      isMultiComment = false
   elseif isPHP && isSingleComment
                && (phpcode[i->1] == '\n') then
      isSingleComment = false
   elseif isPHP && !(isSingleQuote || isDoubleQuote)
                && !(isSingleComment || isMultiComment) 
                && (phpcode[i->1] == '"') then
      isDoubleQuote = true
   elseif isPHP && isDoubleQuote
                && (phpcode[i->1] == '"') then
      isDoubleQuote = false
   elseif isPHP && (isSingleComment || isMultiComment) then
      comments[comments.count - 1] += phpcode[i]
```